# C - mallocing a structure containing various variables gives segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, structure

I have this typedef of a structure containing everything I need:

```
typedef struct item {

    Data_type type;
    union {
        int i;
        double d;
        char *s;
        symt_var *ptr;  
    } value;


    enum op op;
    struct item *lptr;
    struct item *rptr;
} item;
```

When I allocate space for it on the heap for the first time, it's ok, but since the malloc is in iteration, thus allocating new space for new 'item' each time I always get a odd segmentation fault in the second iteration right at the malloc. It has even more odd solution (now, I'm sure it's not solution - but it works), when i do

```
item *new_item = malloc(sizeof(item)+1);
```

instead of

```
item *new_item = malloc(sizeof(item));
```

It somehow works everytime no matter what. Why is that one additional byte needed? How to free it later? Is there any plausible way to calculate the real size of the structure? 
When I do this:

```
sizeof(double)+sizeof(Data_type)+sizeof(op)+(sizeof(item*)*2)
```

I get 32.

```
sizeof(item)   // = 40
```

I need 41...

Relevant piece of code where I get the crash without the +1:

```
void list_add(tPsa_stack *Psa_stack, enum op op)    // 
{
    item *new_item = malloc(sizeof(item)+1);    //alokace noveho itemu
    if (new_item == NULL)
    {
        printErr(ALLOCERROR, INTERNERR);
    }

    new_item->op = op;
    new_item->lptr = NULL;
    new_item->rptr = Psa_stack->top;    // pridani na vrchol zasobniku

    if(Psa_stack->top != NULL)
        Psa_stack->top->lptr = new_item;

    Psa_stack->top = new_item;
}
```

It is called each time I add an element to the list.

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the code where you get the crash.

Comment: I suspect the real problem lies outside the code you posted, but you answer your question, the "real" size of the structure is given by `sizeof`, and it is perfectly normal for the size of the structure to be larger than the size of its members because the compiler is allowed to add padding after each member for alignment purposes. In your case, I suspect the compiler has added 4 bytes of alignment after the `type` member and 4 bytes of padding after the `op` member.

Comment: What do you do with the "value" member of your struct? Is it used within your loop?

Comment: According to your MCVE, while you do check for NULL returned from `malloc()`, you still then go on and attempt to use the `new_item` - not good!

Comment: @IanAbbott Well that would make sense, padding does indeed explain the difference between 32 an 40 but not the 41 needed for allocation by malloc

Comment: @Toby I'm sorry, I should have included that in the code but function printErr does promtly exit the execution of the program. It does not continue after an unsuccessful malloc. It does not even evaluate the if because it crashes right at the malloc.

Comment: @Ronald Yes it is used but not in every iteration. It should be used after the segfault

Comment: @toddddos Great, if `printErr()` does indeed exit the code, that's fine, but if there is some issue there the compiler may otherwise be optimizing your code in such a way that it only *looks* like the failure occurs at that line - this is why it is better to include as close to as possible to your real code

Comment: @Toby I did not know that, thank you. But when I only try to do a printf() right after the malloc it does not print out so it is unlikely the error is somewhere else than in the malloc itself

Comment: @toddddos It is very likely that you are writing outside allocated memory somewhere else in your code (and you happen to be destroying the memory allocation information kept by `malloc`). It is unlikely that the problem is in `malloc`.

Comment: Another idea: are you doing something with multiple threads or signal handling? malloc() is not re-entrant. I had such an error ages ago (with signal handling). I used a printf() call in my signal handler. printf() does a malloc() and if this collides with your malloc() you'll have your SEGV

Comment: @Ronald I'm not creating new threads though

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on some simplified version (omit non standard types such as Data_type) and post here the whole code, including main? I think (as others) that the problem is somewhere else and we are just guessing what might be wrong.